# How to prevent calling a function on every action in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I've a control like below

```
'use strict';
app.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'userService', function (scope, userService) {

$scope.user = {};

getUser();               // PROBLEM

function getUser() {
     // Logic
};

$scope.updateUser= function (user) {
    // Logic
};
}]);
```

**Problem**: The `getUser()` function is executing when i am calling `updateUser`  function. How to prevent `getUser()` method to call on `init` and whenever i required.

Is there any mechanism like `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` in angularjs.

Comment: Is the problem that the function is being called when the controller loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In front-end,

call the function using **ng-click** or **ng-change** events on the field you require-

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="getUser()" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me
</button>
```

And in Controller,

```
$scope.getUser = function () {
  console.log('In getUser');
}
```

To call the function on page-load, use init-

```
'use strict';
app.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'userService', function (scope, userService) {

$scope.user = {};

$scope.getUser = function(){

};

function init(){
  $scope.getUser();
}

init();
}]);
```

Comment: No.. On page load i want get the login user info... not on the button click.

Comment: Call the function  using init(); which will be called for every page load.

Comment: I am not able to get you.what is div init()? Are you saying about ng-init.